# Flutter - Marquee isn't defined for class 'MyApp'

Tags: flutter, dart, marquee

I want to use the `Marquee` inside the body but it is showing an error it is not defined in the class `MyApp`

```
  body: Center(
          child: Row (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget> [
              Marquee (
                child: Text('hello world!',           
          style: TextStyle (
            color: Colors.blueAccent, 
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                   fontSize: 40)
                  )
              ),
            ],
        ),
        ),
```

How to use `Marquee` inside the body?

Answer (score 0):

Add marque lib in dependency at pubspec.yaml file And save. [marquee](https://pub.dev/packages/marquee#-installing-tab-)

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  marquee: ^1.3.1
```

After import:

```
import 'package:marquee/marquee.dart';
```

You can use

```
 body: Center(
          child: Row (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget> [
              Marquee (
                child: Text('hello world!',           
          style: TextStyle (
            color: Colors.blueAccent, 
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                   fontSize: 40)
                  )
              ),
            ],
        ),
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you! @AhmadAghazadeh but im getting an error i.e,  Target of URI doesn't exist: `'package:marquee/marquee.dart'` Even i tried importing `'package:marquee_flutter/marquee_flutter.dart'` but im getting the same error